# How to copy paste values from another dataset conditional on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1

```
    Id Data    Group_Id
0    1 A         1
1    2 B         2
2    3 B         3
      ...
100  4 A         101
101  5 A         102
      ...
```

and df2

```
      Timestamp           Group_Id
2012-01-01 00:00:05.523    1
2013-07-01 00:00:10.757    2
2014-01-12 00:00:15.507.   3
                   ...
2016-03-05 00:00:05.743    101
2017-12-24 00:00:10.407    102
                   ...
```

I want to match the 2 datasets by `Group_Id`, then copy only `date` from `Timestamp` in df2 and paste to a new column in df1 based on corresponding `Group_Id`, name the column `day1`.

Then I want to add **6 more columns** next to `day1`, name them `day2`, ..., `day7` with the next six days based on day1. So it looks like:

```
    Id Data    Group_Id    day1    day2       day3        ...    day7  
0    1 A         1      2012-01-01 2012-01-02 2012-01-03         ...
1    2 B         2      2013-07-01 2013-07-02 2013-07-03         ...
2    3 B         3      2014-01-12 2014-01-13 2014-01-14         ...
                              ...
100  4 A         101    2016-03-05 2016-03-06 2016-03-07         ...
101  5 A         102    2017-12-24 2017-12-25 2017-12-26         ...
                              ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need `merge` here

```
df1=df1.merge(df2,how='left')
s=pd.DataFrame([pd.date_range(x,periods=6,freq ='D') for x in df1.Timestamp],index=df1.index)
s.columns+=1
df1.join(s.add_prefix('Day'))
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach here, basically just merges the dfs, grabs the date from the timestamp and makes 6 new columns adding a day each time:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Group_Id')

df3['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Timestamp']) #only necessary if not already timestamp
df3['day1'] = df3['Timestamp'].dt.date

for i in (range(1,7)):
    df3['day'+str(i+1)] = df3['day1'] + pd.Timedelta(i,unit='d')
```

output:

```
   Id Data  Group_Id               Timestamp        day1        day2        day3        day4        day5        day6        day7
0   1    A         1 2012-01-01 00:00:05.523  2012-01-01  2012-01-02  2012-01-03  2012-01-04  2012-01-05  2012-01-06  2012-01-07
1   2    B         2 2013-07-01 00:00:10.757  2013-07-01  2013-07-02  2013-07-03  2013-07-04  2013-07-05  2013-07-06  2013-07-07
2   3    B         3 2014-01-12 00:00:15.507  2014-01-12  2014-01-13  2014-01-14  2014-01-15  2014-01-16  2014-01-17  2014-01-18
3   4    A       101 2016-03-05 00:00:05.743  2016-03-05  2016-03-06  2016-03-07  2016-03-08  2016-03-09  2016-03-10  2016-03-11
4   5    A       102 2017-12-24 00:00:10.407  2017-12-24  2017-12-25  2017-12-26  2017-12-27  2017-12-28  2017-12-29  2017-12-30
```

note that I copied your data frame into a csv and only had the 5 entires so the index is not the same as your example (i.e. 100, 101)

you can delete the timestamp col if not needed